two symbols in escapechar in lstset (listings package) doesn't work
I am using listings package. When I include only one symbol in escapechar, Latex works fine.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapechar=\%}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing 1: %\label{listing1}%

test 2: [ something between ]

Listing 2:  %\label{listing2}%
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

But, as soon as another symbol is added, Latex doesn't escape any symbol.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapechar=\%, escapeinside={<}{>}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing 1: %\label{listing1}%

test 2: [ something between ]

Listing 2:  %\label{listing2}%
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

Thank you

escapeinside cancels the escapechar feature: you can only have one of them.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{escapechar=\%}

\begin{lstlisting}
Listing 1: %\label{listing1}%

test 2: [ something between ]

Listing 2:  %\label{listing2}%
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{escapeinside=<>}

\begin{lstlisting}
Listing 1: <\label{listing1}>

test 2: [ something between ] %not escaped%

Listing 2:  <\label{listing2}>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


